# How to iterate a for loop into to an array in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, foreach

I am using [react-native-calendars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars) for showing monthly activity and each days. I have an array of data fetched from API, the values are as follows :

```
deliveryDates: Array(3)
0: {date: "2019-02-03", deliveryStatus: false, endingDay: false, startingDay: true}
1: {date: "2019-02-04", deliveryStatus: false, endingDay: false, startingDay: true}
2: {date: "2019-02-05", deliveryStatus: false, endingDay: false, startingDay: false}
```

The calendar library has a property called `markedDates` as it accepts objects alone.

Example of markedDates:

```
markedDates={
{
 '2012-05-04': {disabled: true, startingDay: true, color: 'green', endingDay: true}
}}
```

Now, what I need is to iterate the whole
 `"'2012-05-04': {disabled: true, startingDay: true, color: 'green', endingDay: true}"` with the dates from my API.

So if I have three dates, it should get a iteration of three dates with three new functions as above showed.

But, how to do `foreach` or `for` within the `markedDates` property ? As it shows errors over all ":" and ",". I tried everything .

Please guide

Comment: paste your code on jsfiddle and I'll fix it for you. :)

Comment: wait let me paste and get back ! @AsimKhan

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ebt2g1s6/ @AsimKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the `markedDates` object:

```js
const deliveryDates = [{date:"2019-02-03",deliveryStatus:false,endingDay:false,startingDay:true},{date:"2019-02-04",deliveryStatus:false,endingDay:false,startingDay:true},{date:"2019-02-05",deliveryStatus:false,endingDay:false,startingDay:false}];

const markedDates = deliveryDates.reduce((acc, {date,endingDay,startingDay}) => {
  acc[date] = {disabled: true, color: 'green', startingDay, endingDay};
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(markedDates)
```

Comment: Actually, i am asking how to implement this into the markedDates Property of <Calendar />

Comment: Use this `markedDates` variable in the calendar. I'm not really familiar with react but something like this? `<Calendar markedDates={markedDates} />`

Comment: actually, the data i am getting is in array. But the markedDates get only objects as value. This is the example of markedDates `markedDates={
    {'2012-05-20': {textColor: 'green'},
     '2012-05-22': {startingDay: true, color: 'green'},
     '2012-05-23': {selected: true, endingDay: true, color: 'green', textColor: 'gray'},
     '2012-05-04': {disabled: true, startingDay: true, color: 'green', endingDay: true}
    }}
`

Comment: So, i need to iterate the dates from api. in the places of dates in the above example. So if there is 3 dates , then 3 new lines should be formed under marked date

Comment: In the snippet I created, `deliveryDates` is an array. `markedDates` is an object in the format you requested. Click on "Run code snippet" to check it. I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: @Arvindh But this is not the expected output you posted in the question. Where did `textColor` come from. Why do only some dates have `selected`, `color` and `startingDay`? What is the criteria? I think i'll delete my answer since I'm not sure what you need

Comment: Brother , selected and color etc will be taken from API , the first thing which I need is date , so by that I can use for others like selected , color , startingDay !

Comment: @Arvindh *"selected and color etc will be taken from API"*. Where in the question have you mentioned this. There is no `color` inside `deliveryDates`. Please provide the *actual* input and *output* you need in the question to create a [mcve]